# Graphing collaborators in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have a simple graph database of people and projects.  The only relations are who worked on what projects.  How can I find and graph the project collaborations between people?

I'm hoping to end up with a graph of just people, with connecting lines for collaborations.

I tried this query, but it only returns nodes, not relations:

```
MATCH (valjean:person {person_id: "24601"})-[:WORKED_ON]->(project)<-[:WORKED_ON]-(collaborators)
RETURN valjean, collaborators;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a variable to the relation, and return it - like so:

```
MATCH (valjean:person {person_id: "24601"})-[r1:WORKED_ON]->(project)<-[r2:WORKED_ON]-(collaborators)
RETURN valjean, r1, r2, collaborators;
```

I added "r1" and "r2" to report the relations as well as the nodes.

Here's another way to do the same thing:

```
MATCH (valjean:person {person_id: "24601"})-[r1:WORKED_ON]->(project)
MATCH (collaborators:person)-[r2:WORKED_ON]->(project)
RETURN valjean, r1, r2, collaborators;
```

Using the "movie" example, here's how to find everybody else that was part of a movie project other than Halle Berry:

```
match (p1:Person {name: "Halle Berry"})-[r]-(m:Movie {title: "Cloud Atlas"})
match (m)-[p]-(p2:Person)
where p1 <> p2
return m, p, p2
```

If the objective is to get the result in a "report" format, this'll give you what you're looking for - it won't give you a graph though.

```
match (p1:Person {name: "Halle Berry"})-[r]-(m:Movie {title: "Cloud Atlas"})
match (m)-[p]-(p2:Person)
where p1 <> p2
return p1, "WORKED_WITH", p2
```

Comment: This is very close, but it still shows the project nodes.  Is there a way to show just the people and their inherited relations?

Comment: I'm not sure what "inherited relations" mean. If you could elaborate I'd could give you a suggestion.

Comment: I want to show just the people, and have relationships based on what projects they worked on together.  Basically, a `"WORKED_WITH"` relation derived from the `"WORKED_ON"` relations.

Comment: Do you want to create these "worked with" relations in the db?

Comment: I don't know what the tradeoff would be in regards to calculating them on the fly vs. storing them.  I suppose the disk space is just about negligible.

Comment: The issue  is I don't think you can report inferred relationships the way you're asking for - they have to be stored. If "worked_with" is stored in the db, then the next question would be "when & how" which brings us back to the projects.

Comment: I've added an example using the "movie" data - it shows the type of participation everybody but the person in question (Halle Berry) in the movie "Cloud Atlas"

Comment: If adding the `"WORKED_WITH"` relations is necessary, how would I do so?

Comment: Changing "RETURN valjean, r1, r2, collaborators" to "MERGE (valjean)-[:WORKED_WITH]-(collaborators)" will give you the collaboration relationships you're looking for.